# How to add button functionality to created elements by innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

How to make the function of adding new sections and subsections work on the created sections.

```js
'use strict';

const btnNewChapter = document.querySelector('.btn-new-chapter');
const btnAddChapter = document.querySelector('.btn-add-chapter');
const btnAddSubChapter = document.querySelector('.btn-add-sub-chapter');

const main = document.querySelector('.main');
const mainBody = document.querySelector('.main-body');
const chapterListBody = document.querySelector('.chapter-list-body');

let appData = [];

btnNewChapter.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const ol = document.createElement('ol');
    ol.classList.add('main-body');
    ol.innerHTML = '<ul class="chapter-list">' +
                    '<li class="chapter-list-title">' +
                    '<div class="data">' +
                    '<h1 class="title">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="chapter-title" placeholder="Chapter Title">' +
                    '</h1>' +
                    '<button class="btn-add-chapter">Add Body Text</button>' +
                    '<button class="btn-add-sub-chapter">Add SubBody Text</button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +

                    '<ul class="chapter-list-body">' +
                    '<li class="chapter-list-text">' +
                    '<div class="chapter">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="chapter-text" placeholder="Chapter Body">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</li>' +
                    '</ul>';
    main.append(ol);
})

btnAddChapter.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('chapter-list-text');
    li.innerHTML = '<div class="chapter">' + 
                    '<input type="text" class="chapter-text" placeholder="Chapter Body">' +
                    '</div>';
    chapterListBody.append(li);
});

btnAddSubChapter.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('sub-chapter-list-text');
    li.innerHTML = '<div class="subchapter">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="sub-chapter-text" placeholder="SubChapter Body">' +
                    '</div>';
    chapterListBody.append(li);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body class='main'>

<button class="btn-new-chapter">Add New Chapter</button>
<ol class="main-body">
    <ul class="chapter-list">
        <li class="chapter-list-title">
            <div class="data">
                <h1 class="title">
                    <input type="text" class="chapter-title" placeholder="Chapter Title">
                </h1>
                <button class="btn-add-chapter">Add Body Text</button>
                <button class="btn-add-sub-chapter">Add SubBody Text</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="chapter-list-body">
        <li class="chapter-list-text">
            <div class="chapter">
                <input type="text" class="chapter-text" placeholder="Chapter Body">
            </div>
        </li>

        <!-- <li class="sub-chapter-list-text">
            <div class="subchapter">
                <input type="text" class="sub-chapter-text" placeholder="Тело Подраздела">
            </div>
        </li> -->
    </ul>
</ol>
<script src="/scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Next I am going to add button "Save Data", what will add inputs value and chapters to local storage and "remove" button, what will remove chapters, subchapters or titles from local storage and update the page?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're creating the event listeners before you insert the HTML.
That way your listeners can't be attached to those new items.
You also can't just re-run the event listener after you added the HTML or the events will stack up on the already added HTML resulting in duplication of functionality.

What I did here is I added a `counter` variable that keeps track of what event goes where.
I also removed the HTML from you HTML file and re-used the same function again for the very first run. That way you don't have the HTML in your code twice.

You don't have to use a counter. You could also use a class you add or remove to keep track of what already has the event but I thought this was the easiest to explain.

```js
'use strict';

const main = document.querySelector('.main');
let counter = 0;

function addChapterHtml(counter) {
    const chapterListBody = document.querySelector(`.chapter-list-body.counter${counter}`);
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('chapter-list-text');
    li.innerHTML = '<div class="chapter">' + 
                    '<input type="text" class="chapter-text" placeholder="Chapter Body">' +
                    '</div>';
    chapterListBody.append(li);
}

function addSubChapterHtml(counter) {
    const chapterListBody = document.querySelector(`.chapter-list-body.counter${counter}`);
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('sub-chapter-list-text');
    li.innerHTML = '<div class="subchapter">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="sub-chapter-text" placeholder="SubChapter Body">' +
                    '</div>';
    chapterListBody.append(li);
}

function addNewChapterHtml() {
    counter ++;
    const ol = document.createElement('ol');
    ol.classList.add('main-body');
    ol.innerHTML = '<ul class="chapter-list">' +
            '<li class="chapter-list-title">' +
                '<div class="data">' +
                    '<h1 class="title">' +
                        '<input type="text" class="chapter-title" placeholder="Chapter Title">' +
                    '</h1>' +
                    '<button class="btn-add-chapter counter' + counter + '">Add Body Text</button>' +
                    '<button class="btn-add-sub-chapter counter' + counter + '">Add SubBody Text</button>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</li>' +
        '</ul>' +

        '<ul class="chapter-list-body counter' + counter + '">' +
            '<li class="chapter-list-text">' +
                '<div class="chapter">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="chapter-text" placeholder="Chapter Body">' +
                '</div>' +
            '</li>' +
        '</ul>';
    main.append(ol);

  // after adding the HTML into your DOM we attach the event listeners to those new buttons
    document
        .querySelector(`.btn-add-chapter.counter${counter}`)
        .addEventListener('click', () => addChapterHtml(counter));
    document
        .querySelector(`.btn-add-sub-chapter.counter${counter}`)
        .addEventListener('click', () => addSubChapterHtml(counter));
}
// this event listener can be added right now since the button is in the HTML already
document
  .querySelector('.btn-new-chapter')
  .addEventListener('click', addNewChapterHtml);

// Now let's use the functions we created above to add the first sections
addNewChapterHtml();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body class='main'>

<button class="btn-new-chapter">Add New Chapter</button>

<script src="/scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```